# How to implement Login using Membership provider into MVC 4 application ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, membership-provider

I want to implement login/change password/forget password into MVC 4 Application.

Can any one guide me how i could achieve this using Membershiop in MVC 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

** This type of open ended question are normally down voted. You need to be more specific with the problem you are facing and share your analysis. **

I will try to give you some pointer if you have not already figure out from a simple google search.

You can use `SimpleMembershipProvider` if your are using MVC 4. If you create a new MVC 4 application in Visual Studio, you will get a precooked working form authentication enabled internet application.

Go through the code in `AccountController`, you will find most of the functionality already implemented with the help of `WebSecurity` wrapper class. Go from there and share specific issue you face.

You can refer following two links to start with:

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/using-simplemembership-in-asp.net-mvc-4.htm

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/689801/Understanding-and-Using-Simple-Membership-Provider